# Graph optimization into a tree graph with an optimization formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, optimization, trees, discrete-optimization

Assuming that we have a graph where all nodes have at least one edge connected to others and an optimization formula based on multiple factors, what optimization solutions there are to create a tree graph from the original graph by erasing the edges?

Comment: Which formula??

Comment: Are you looking for the [minimum spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree)?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo It would be a complex formula that doesn't actually matter. It is similar to the minimum spanning tree but without weights and instead of optimizing based on the minimum cost of the weights it would try to minimize the optimization formula based on connections.

Comment: Please provide a toy example.  I still have no idea what you want to do

Comment: The formula definitely *does* "actually matter". If there are no patterns to exploit in the formula, then no intelligent algorithm is possible; the only correct solution is to check every single spanning tree to see which achieves the best value.